# Assign List<Something<?>> to List<Something<Object>>

Tags: java, generics

I'm running into some issues with generics and captured types that I can't figure out what the neat solution is.

I've got a variable containing a `List<Something<Object>>` and I want to be able to call `list.add(Something<?>)` and `list.addAll(List<Something<?>>)`, but the compiler does not accept either directly.

What are the options to be able to do this?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't accept it that way and you can't change them both to `Object` or `?`, casting is probably your only option.

Comment: @Schred Is casting these safe? If so, why does it require a cast instead of being able to do the conversion implicitly? And what's the correct way to cast the addAll argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the `List<SomeThing<Object>>` with `List<SomeThing<? extends Object>>` ?  If so here are some options;

```
public class StackOverflow {

    static class SomeThing<T> { 
        private T t;
        public SomeThing(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return t.toString();
        }
    };


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<SomeThing<? extends Object>> sList = new ArrayList<>();

        sList.add(new SomeThing<Integer>(1));
        sList.add(new SomeThing<String>("1"));

        System.out.println(sList);

        add(new SomeThing<Integer>(1), sList);
        add(new SomeThing<String>("1"), sList);

        System.out.println(sList);

        List<SomeThing<String>> ssList = new ArrayList<>();
        ssList.add(new SomeThing<String>("a"));
        ssList.add(new SomeThing<String>("b"));

        sList.addAll(ssList);
        addAll(ssList, sList);

        System.out.println(sList);

        List<SomeThing<Integer>> siList = new ArrayList<>();
        siList.add(new SomeThing<Integer>(1));
        siList.add(new SomeThing<Integer>(2));

        sList.addAll(siList);
        addAll(siList, sList);

        System.out.println(sList);


    }

    public static void add(SomeThing<?> st, List<SomeThing<?>> stl) {
        stl.add(st);
    } 

    public static <T> void addAll(List<SomeThing<T>> st, List<SomeThing<?>> stl) {
        stl.addAll(st);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is the route I went for. I was under the impression that `List<Something<Object>>` would more clearly indicate that you are able to deal with any type of Something, and `?` would indicate some specific, but unknown type. In practice though, using `List<Something<?>>` works perfectly, and you can add any Somethings to it without casting.
Note that `? extends Object` is equivalent to just `?`, the superfluous `extends Object` can generate warnings in some IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

The TLDR; I'm going to assume you don't have power over whatever API is giving you a `List<Something<?>>`, so I would suggest casting.

A wildcard `?` in generics does not mean that it could be any type, it means that it is of *some* type that we don't know in this context. And even though all types are subtypes of Object, since Java's generics are invariant, `Something</*Any type*/>` is not equivalent to `Something<Object>`.

If you are very sure that below, `wildList`, which is of type `List<Something<?>>` contains only objects of type `Something<Object>` you can cast it to a `List` of `Something<Object>`. However, it's not a great idea otherwise to use wildcards without any bounds whatsoever.

```
public static void method(List<Something<?>> wildList) {
  List<Something<Object>> objList = wildList; //This won't work
  objList = (List<Something<Object>>) wildList; //This will work
}
```

Comment: I was unaware that Java's generics are invariant, which seems to be the root of the issue.

What would go wrong if you cast `List<Something<?>>` to `List<Something<Object>>` where ? is any class, eg, extends from Object?

Comment: Actually, nothing would go wrong at runtime, since types are erased and all objects extend Object. However, if you expected it to be a Something that holds something more specific, such as a String, and you instead got a Something that holds an Integer, there would be a ClassCastException, which of course is not good.

Comment: Makes sense! So as long as you're casting `?` to `Object` you're safe, anything else and you're in unsafe territory.

Comment: Right, although if you have a bound like ? extends Foo, that's also fine (Like the other answer suggested).